# change href attribute of anchor tags from homepage.html to ../homepage.html

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, href

I am having a navbar having links to homepage and other stuffs and it is same for every page so it is only kept in home directory and linked with  other htmls. The problem I am having is with the anchor tags as different files are kept in different directories, so the relative link to homepage and other stuff will also differ. For example let my home directory name be 'abc' and homepage and navbar is located in this directory as 'abc/homepage.html' and 'abc/navbar.html'. Anchor tags works well on homepage but in different directory it doesn't. As if I access it from 'abc/def/otherPage.html' it isn't working in other page as now homepage link is '../homepage.html' rather than just 'homepage.html'. Someone plz suggest a solution out of this problem.

Comment: The simplest way of resolving this would be to change your file structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you need to use absolute path for links, for example "/abc/homepage.html", not "abc/homepage.html". In this case no matter from where you click to this link you will come to /abc/homepage.html

Comment: as  it came out just  a backslash in the beginning did the trick. Backslash  made anchor  tag to reference to the home location as i intended thank you. The only thing that  was different was that i didn't  need to include the directory name in it as  my local server was running itsef inside the main directory.